# Track and count clicks with AngularJS and post to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, mongodb, mongoose

I want to be able to track the click from a user on an item and have it update the JSON object associate with it and display the number of all the clicks. I know how to create and delete an object, but how do I add a new name and value and update the object when the user clicks and appropriate vote button? Any help will be greatly appreciated and I thank you in advance.

The HTML

```
<body ng-controller="mainController">
<div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <td>Vote</td>
                <td>Song</td>
                <td>Edit</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="todo in todos">
                <td><button class="btn btn-success icon-thumbs-up" alt="Up vote this song if you like it.">Vote</button></td>
                <td>{{ todo.text }}</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-danger fa fa-times" ng-click="deleteTodo(todo._id)" alt="Remove the song if you need to make an edit and then add it back."></button></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
</body>
```

The Model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('Todo', {
text : String,
done : Boolean
});
```

The Service

```
angular.module('todoService', [])

// super simple service
// each function returns a promise object 
.factory('Todos', function($http) {
    return {
        get : function() {
            return $http.get('/api/todos');
        },
        create : function(todoData) {
            return $http.post('/api/todos', todoData);
        },
        delete : function(id) {
            return $http.delete('/api/todos/' + id);
        }
    }
});
```

Server side Angular

```
var Todo = require('./models/todo');

module.exports = function(app) {

// api ---------------------------------------------------------------------
// get all todos
app.get('/api/todos', function(req, res) {

    // use mongoose to get all todos in the database
    Todo.find(function(err, todos) {

        // if there is an error retrieving, send the error. nothing after res.send(err) will execute
        if (err)
            res.send(err)

        res.json(todos); // return all todos in JSON format
    });
});

// create todo and send back all todos after creation
app.post('/api/todos', function(req, res) {

    // create a todo, information comes from AJAX request from Angular
    Todo.create({
        text : req.body.text,
        done : false
    }, function(err, todo) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        // get and return all the todos after you create another
        Todo.find(function(err, todos) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err)
            res.json(todos);
        });
    });

});

// delete a todo
app.delete('/api/todos/:todo_id', function(req, res) {
    Todo.remove({
        _id : req.params.todo_id
    }, function(err, todo) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        // get and return all the todos after you create another
        Todo.find(function(err, todos) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err)
            res.json(todos);
        });
    });
});

// application -------------------------------------------------------------
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./public/index.html'); // load the single view file (angular will handle the page changes on the front-end)
});
```

};

Client side Angular

```
angular.module('todoController', [])

// inject the Todo service factory into our controller
.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http, Todos) {
    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.loading = true;

    // GET =====================================================================
    // when landing on the page, get all todos and show them
    // use the service to get all the todos
    Todos.get()
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.todos = data;
            $scope.loading = false;
        });

    // CREATE ==================================================================
    // when submitting the add form, send the text to the node API
    $scope.createTodo = function() {
        $scope.loading = true;

        if ($scope.formData.text != undefined) {

            // call the create function from our service (returns a promise object)
        Todos.create($scope.formData)

            // if successful creation, call our get function to get all the new todos
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.loading = false;
                $scope.formData = {}; // clear the form so our user is ready to enter another
                $scope.todos.unshift(data); // assign our new list of todos
                });
            }
        };

    // DELETE ==================================================================
    // delete a todo after checking it
    $scope.deleteTodo = function(id) {
        $scope.loading = true;

        Todos.delete(id)
            // if successful creation, call our get function to get all the new todos
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.loading = false;
                $scope.todos = data; // assign our new list of todos
            });
    };

});
```

Comment: do you mean how do you "add a new name and value and update the object" in the database?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Yes basically that is what I want to do, but I also want it to add up all the clicks for each object.

Comment: you can use the update $inc operator: db.coll.update({criteria:here},{$inc:{counter:1}}) will increment the counter by 1 if it exists and set it to 1 if it doesn't exist (i.e. increment it from implicit value of 0 when it doesn't exist).  That sounds like it's sufficient for what you described and then you don't need to do any adding after the fact.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Thanks. Would I put that in a function and then have an ng-click on the button calling that function?

Comment: that I cannot say, since I'm not sure how exactly your application needs to do this.  Is the intent that when a button is clicked on some object then you increment a specific field?  Are there multiple buttons?  Multiple things you will be tracking counters for?

Comment: Yes there will be multiple buttons. Each todo will have a button that will have its own votes. I suppose I need to rewrite my question and be more specific to what I am looking to do.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you would do.

Add a new field to schema to store the votes:

```
votes: {type: Number, default: 0}
```

Add a new handler on the server side to increment `vote` when it gets a request:

```
app.get('/api/todos/:todo_id/vote', function(req, res) {
    Todo.update({_id: req.params.todo_id}, { $inc: {votes: 1} } ), function(err,doc){
    ...
    }
}
```

Add a new function to AngularJS service to call this new API handler:

```
vote: function(id) {
    return $http.get('/api/todos/' + id + '/vote');
}
```

Wire up ngClick on ngRepeated elements to call the new Svc function.  **NOTE:** You would need `Todos` svc in your scope to do this as below, otherwise create a wrapper function in the scope as you have done.

```
<td>
  <button data-ng-click="Todos.vote(todo._id)" 
    class="btn.." alt="Up vote this....">Vote
  </button>
</td>
```

then display in your view somehow the new "votes" field of the ToDo Models coming back.

Check this out: http://meanjs.org/  You can get a lot of good examples working with Angular, node and Mongo, look at the "articles" module that comes with it.

I didn't try any of this but it should give you the basic idea what to do.  Also, realize there is nothing here to stop a user from upvoting more than once.  Hope it helps!

Comment: It doesn't seem to be adding the clicks to vote. What do you mean by a wrapper function? Do you mean the functions such as $scope.deleteTodo?

Comment: yes like deleteTodo.  the above shld work, what error did you see?

Comment: I am getting no errors in the console with the above code and a wrapper. $scope.updateTodo = function(id) {
   $scope.loading = true;

   Todos.vote(id)
    // if successful creation, call our get function to get all the new todos
    .success(function(data) {
     $scope.loading = false;
     $scope.todos = data; // assign our new list of todos
    });
  };

Comment: @aaronsil Actually it looks like I am getting this. GET http://somedomain.com/api/todos/undefined/vote 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Well, the todoID is null, but it's too little information to tell why.

Comment: @aaronsil You have certainly pointed me in the right direction. I don't know how else to find an error. You have helped me on another question and I thank you for that. All I could think of is showing you the live site with the code.

Comment: Print a bunch of console.log and see why todoId is null, track it from angular side down to backend express/node/db piece

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57362/discussion-between-aarosil-and-justin).

Comment: Interesting now when I try to delete a Todo I get this {"message":"Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"undefined\" at path \"_id\"","name":"CastError","type":"ObjectId","value":"undefined","path":"_id"}

Comment: OMG I think I figured it out. Hold on.